# How to attribute a column value (dollars) to a different column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I'm not sure how to phrase this question. Tableau makes this process extremley easy, but in python I'm stumped. I've got three types of columns. The first type is a unique_id. The second type is a boolean classification for small business (example: Veteran Owned Small Business, YES/NO). The third type is dollars obligated.

It looks like this:

| Unique_ID | Veteran_Flag | Woman_Owned_Flag | Dollars_Obligated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6824295 | Yes | No | 145768 |
| 8294347 | No | Yes | 0 |
| 9374276 | No | Yes | 824999 |

My goal is to make a bar graph that shows the total amount of dollars obligated associated with each flag. I usually use tableau, which makes this a 3 minute drill, but no clue how to do it in pandas. (There are over 10 different flags and thousands of rows FYI)

Comment: please provide a slightly larger example with other flags

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data based on the column values:

```
# Get your DataFrame - however you want to

# Split into you two identifiers
vet_flag = df[df["Veteran_flag"] == True]
no_vet_flag = df[df["Veteran_flag"] == False]

# Sum total in each column
total_dollars_vet = vet_flag["Dollars_obligated"].sum()
total_dollars_no_vet = vet_flag["Dollars_oblidated"].sum()

# Graph using matplotlib : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_bar_plot.htm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
types = ['Veteran flag', 'Non-veteran Flag']
values = [total_dollars_vet, total_dollars_no_vet]
ax.bar(types, values)
plt.show()
```

Not that you can adapt this to use `woman_owned_flag` where need be. In the example, they (vet & woman) look exactly opposite, so it is ambiguous how you want it formatted, but this should work within reason regardless.

Comment: Thanks Larry the Llama. I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Going to try this out and see if it works. I will probably need to write a for loop to do it for each flag. There is a flag for each demographic in my data set (i.e. black_owned, hispanic_owned, asian_owned, etc.).